# Running client and server modules in Noflo

Tags: noflo

I have a noflo Node.js runtime set up with a hosted Noflo-UI. Is there any way to run client-side modules in the same graph as the Node.js runtime? I need to upload an image file, send it to the server, then send it back and display it in the preview window. Thank you very much for any input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot run them in the same graph, but you can use a noflo-nodejs runtime as a component in the noflo-browser one. You need to add noflo-runtime as a dependency in your component.json (for browser) and declare the runtime. [Example](https://github.com/jonnor/noflo-browser-app/commit/8bf2019122e12b1755d5b29f8d9297a8e86e92b9)